# Add a class to post_class if more than one post shares same meta_value_num

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta, post-class

I would like to be able to add a class such as `.samedate` to posts that share the same `meta_value_num` from a custom meta box.

So for example:
Say two posts share the same custom meta box value for a date entered as `2013/11/03`... If those two posts have the same meta value number, then add the class to those posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('post_class', function($classes){
  global $wp_query;
  static $meta = array();       

  // first call gathers meta values
  if(!$meta)
    foreach($wp_query->posts as $post)
      $meta[$post->ID] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_meta_key', true);

  // $wp_query->post should be the global (current) $post object
  $this_meta = $meta[$wp_query->post->ID];

  if($this_meta){
    $counts = array_count_values($meta);

    if($counts[$this_meta] > 1)
      $classes[] = 'your_class';
  }   

  return $classes;
});
```

*(untested)*

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks for the quick response as well!